# Kill system call C, permission

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

Why does sending kill system call in C doesn't require root access or sudoer permission? I was trying to terminate a process in C, using the kill system call. I though it would require me to run process as root but it didn't. Normally while sending kill system call through bash terminal, We are required to use sudo, then Why isn't it necessary while using C?

Comment: "*We are required to use sudo*" - No, you're not. `kill` simply sends a signal. You are allowed to send signals to your own processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the program `kill` on the command line and you don't have the required permissions then it will fail.  The same thing can happen when using `kill()` from a C program.  See the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) page for information.

Specifically the section on return values `EPERM` is returned if the user doesn't have permission to send to any of the process ids listed.  And the description:

> For a process to have permission to send a signal to a process designated by pid, unless the sending process has appropriate privileges, the real or effective user ID of the sending process shall match the real or saved set-user-ID of the receiving process.